# WIFI connection in Android ICS 4.0.4 with ksoap2 library

Tags: android, wifi, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, ksoap2

I am using Samsung S3 (ICS 4.0.4).
I encounter a problem with ksoap2 library over WIFI.

My webservice doesn't work sometimes using ksoap2 library when WIFI connection is used.

It throws an exception,

```
 java.net.SocketTimeoutException at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:130)
```

I have to use webService with ksoap2.

****The main point is it works perfectly with 3G connection but not on WIFI**

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Seem your wifi network in not working good.

Comment: No its not the case, because the same WIFI network works fine in android 2.3.3 device.

Comment: I have the same issue. The same operation that works most of the time, might not work specially right after I unlock the device, maybe it takes a bit for Wi-Fi to kick in. Unfortunately, I did not get the chance to test with 3G but I'm just hoping it will resolve itself once I switch to 3G.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to set a higher Timeout value, like this:

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000);
```

timeout value is the second param. That should atleast help you identify, if this is a problem with your web service or something else.